# Wordpress - How to add HTML/Text to Excerpt and then add auto Excerpt

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to add an image or some HTML\text **before** the post excerpt, but when I add it to the excerpt block below the post edit, it overrides the excerpt fully,
is there a shortcode or a way to display the auto excerpt after my line of code?

for example:

```
<p>My code whatever</p>

<short-code-for-auto-excerpt>
```

which will display both as the excerpt.

thanks

Comment: what do you mean it overrides the excerpt fully?

Comment: I think you need this type of plugin which allow user to add html markup in excerpt,link-https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/

Comment: @ProEvilz I mean when i enter something in the excerpt box, it "deletes" the auto excerpt and shows only what I wrote in the excerpt box.
See: http://shanziv.co.il/
at the bottom there are 3 previews of posts, the left one has a small black and white box, that's the HTML i inserted in the Excerpt box, and it overrides the automatic excerpt generated when the excerpt box is empty. I want to add the automatic generated excerpt below my HTML.

SouvikSikdar i will try it thanks